# Insert many multi-level arrays into mysql base

Tags: php, mysql

i have a function what separate my file's content. Example file:

```
001;"text1"
002;"text2"
003;"text3"
999
001;"tekst11"
```

Sometimes some indexes have a few values:

```
120;"text2"
120;"text3"
```

My function:

```
function parseCSV($file) {
   $lines = file($file);
   $output = array();
   $i = -1;
   foreach($lines as $line) {
      $line = trim($line);
      if($line == "999") {
         $i++;
      } else {
         $ex = explode(";", $line, 2);
         $val = str_replace("\"", "", $ex[1]);
         //$dodaj = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `czynsz` (`$ex[$i]`) VALUES ('$val')");
         if(isset($output[$i][$ex[0]])) {         
            if(is_array($output[$i][$ex[0]])) {

               $output[$i][$ex[0]][] = $val;
            } else {
               $output[$i][$ex[0]] = array($output[$i][$ex[0]], $val);
            }
         } else {
            $output[$i][$ex[0]] = $val;
         }
         $dodaj = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `czynsz` (`$ex[$i]`) VALUES ('$val')");
      }
   }
   return $output;
}
$csvdata = parseCSV("woda.txt");


echo "<pre>\r\n";
print_r($csvdata);
echo "</pre>\r\n";
```

Above script makes me multi-level array tree and separate arrays from themselves by separator (999), because in my file are many arrays... When an index has many values - the script makes for him internal tree. For example:

```
Array
    (
    [0] => Array
        (
        [001] => 06-001-03-13
        [002] => 06447
        [003] => F
        ...
        [097] =>
        [120] => Array
            (
            [0] => text1
            [1] => text2
            )
        )
    [1] => Array
    ...
```

**And there is my question:**
I have a problem with save this mega array in my MySQL base. Every index in array have the same in data base. When the same index will have many values (ex. 120) it can be implode. Thank you with all my heart for any form of help... :(

Comment: The `mysql`-extension is outdated, its usage is _highly_ discouraged and it will be flagged as deprecated with the upcoming PHP5.5. Use `MySQLi`, or `PDO_MYSQL` instead. See the notice http://php.net/en/mysql-connect

Comment: why do you create a new array index on 999?

Comment: @hek2mgl It's some sort of magic constant I guess

Comment: Please show us dump of the table's structure

Comment: Psst, [`fgetcsv`](http://php.net/fgetcsv)

Comment: He says that he is using 999 is his separator between arrays in the data file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a MySQL Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `czynsz` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL ,
  `value` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

ALTER TABLE `czynsz` ADD UNIQUE `unique` ( `id` )
```

Then use the following php code to insert the data

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL); // just for debugging remove later
ini_set('display_erorrs', 1); // just for debugging remove later

function parseCSV($file) {
    $lines = file($file);
    $output = array();
    $i = 0;
    foreach($lines as $line) {
        $line = trim($line);
        if($line == "999") {
           $i++;
           continue;
        }

        list($id, $val) = explode(";", $line, 2);

        $val = str_replace("\"", "", $val);

        $result = mysql_query("
            INSERT INTO `czynsz` (
                id, 
                `value`
            ) VALUES (
                '$id',
                '$val'
            ) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
                `value` = CONCAT(`value`, ', ', '$val')"
        );
        if(!$result) {
            die(mysql_error());
        }
        if(isset($output[$i][$id])) {
            if(is_array($output[$i][$id])) {
                $output[$i][$id][] = $val;
            } else {
                $output[$i][$id] = array($output[$i][$id], $val);
            }
        } else {
            $output[$i][$id] = $val;
        }
    }
   return $output;
}
```

Comment: `test.czynsz` means database `test` and table `czynsz`

Comment: please check the updates I made! you'll have to use CONCAT in the sql of course.

Comment: do you need the `$output` array for further procession? otherwise I would remove it.

Comment: what errors do you get? can set `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` ?

Comment: If you add `echo $line;` after `$line = trim($line);`.. What does it say?

Comment: The method I posted worked on the data you posted above. I have tested it. This should answer the question above.  There must another error(s) in your solution. This is not part of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Use the PHP sledgehammer solution...

Assuming that you just want to store the array and don't need to query against distinct nodes, use the `serialize` function to turn your array into a string representation. You can easily pull the data and then use `unserialize` to get back the original array.

```
$s_arr = serialize($my_array);

$my_array = unserialize($s_arr);
```

If you need access to the nodes in the database, then I think that MySQL is not a good solution because of the complexity involved. If you want a key-value store, then you should look at a NoSQL solution such as [Redis](http://redis.io/).

Comment: Why not? Personally, I'd use json_encode() as it's easier to read and I understand it's a bit faster, but if he just wants the data back, and isn't (as Ian warns) trying to query against nodes, then serialize is probably a lot faster than having x rows. Many db's are moving into a similar direction (e.g. Mongo).

Comment: @GabrielSantos You only "think" so -- and that deserves a downvote? There is nothing in the OP's question to suggest how the data will be utilized in the database, other than to store it.

Comment: OP' owner wants a key-value approach. And, if I have a million of indexes, how to do a fast search?

Comment: @GabrielSantos Bless your cotton socks... But somebody did... **and they didn't leave a comment**! Grrr! :)

Comment: Two peoples downvoted you (one upvoted), so far, so I think they don't like your approach too.

Comment: @GabrielSantos I think MySQL is probably not a good solution for this. If he wants a key-value store, then he should look at several of the NoSQL solutions. Probably something like [Redis](http://redis.io/) is the way to go.

Comment: Yes, I think too, but, we need to give solution paths without drastically changing the tools used.

Comment: I somewhat agree, but then there is always going to be that "I'm writing my own database software using HTML"-type question that just starts off on the wrong path... oh well.